# After a while getting multiple answers from slack bot using slack-ruby-bot gem

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, slack, slack-api

My slack bot starts answering multiple times after a while.
Restarting the slack bot container resolves the issue temporarily.

We have integrated a slack bot with our ruby app using the **slack-ruby-bot** gem.

See the code for a simple example of how the commands are implemented. In this command whenever a user writes to say 'any_phrase' the bot answers with that exact 'any_phrase'.
This works fine but after a while, the bot starts answering multiple times.

This was implemented with a ***docker container*** so I added logs to verify We get responses from the same machine, not from another container listening. And it's coming from the same IP.
Also, After I restart my container it resolves the issue which also indicates it's coming from the same machine.

```
class Say < SlackRubyBot::Commands::Base
  command 'say' do |client, data, match|
    client.say(channel: data.channel,text: match['expression'])
  end
end
```

The bot should only answer once at all times. There are other commands that affect the app's data and we do not want it to run multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be a confirmed bug with slack-ruby-bot + celluloid, see https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-bot/issues/236. There's a workaround of switching to async-websocket.